# The chrome <input type='range'> always higher then other html element

Tags: google-chrome, input, range

suppose I have a simple container which have three element:

```
<div>
   <span>hello world</span>        
   <input id="ipt" type='test'>
   <input id="rge" type='range'>
</div>
```

but it show the last #rge always higher then the other two,
like this (view in chrome):http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/SYNPa/1/

Why this happened?How can I solve this problem without adding other html element?just work with css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the following CSS to your #rge definition:

`vertical-align:middle;`

This aligns the element centred vertically on the line.